# Retrieving data given month wise

Tags: android, sqlite, date

I am storing some data and date that is selected by user in sqlite in **dd-MMM-yyyy** format in `storeDate` named column with `TEXT` type because afaik there is no `DATE` type directly. Now I want to retrieve the stored data month wise. Suppose I give input as `01-Dec-2013` and build where clause, then I need to get the data of that particular month(Dec, 2013). Can someone Please suggest how to achieve this? My current query is:

```
Cursor cursor= db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+TABLE_NAME+" "+whereClause+" GROUP BY "+CATEGORY, null);
```

What should be given at the place of whereClause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLite [**does not support month names**](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html), sadly. You will have to convert it to a month name either using a lookup table, a case statement, or a switch on the presentation layer.

Try this

```
SELECT strftime('%Y-%m', table_column) FROM `table name` WHERE strftime('%Y-%m',  table_column) = '2013-04'
```

If you want to print the month name only then try this

```
SELECT case  strftime('%m',date_column) when '01' then 'January' when '02' then 'Febuary' when '03' then 'March' when '04' then 'April' when '05' then 'May' when '06' then 'June' when '07' then 'July' when '08' then 'August' when '09' then 'September' when '10' then 'October' when '11' then 'November' when '12' then 'December' else '' end
as month FROM `your_table` WHERE   strftime('%m',date_column)='12'
```

Also take a took at this stuff for more date and time functions in SQLite

[**Date And Time Functions**](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)

Comment: I want to put the condition in where clause and that where clause should be generated based on the given date.

Comment: Thanks for your time, but I am not getting output :( Does that column need to store date(string type) in the format of YYYY-MM-DD?

Comment: Last question, how can we use this in query() method instead of rawquery(), because I must use query or some other method that is provided by framework instead of rawquery.

Answer (score 0):

You could use MySQL's MONTH() function

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE MONTH( trans_date ) = 3
```

Comment: Sorry, my question is regarding sqlite